# How to sum values based on a date?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am Stock trader and each day I incur profits or loss from market. I want to sum up each day's total and fetch the sum values in a separate column to focus on my target:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [SUMIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).

`=SUMIF(Data_Range,Date_Criteria,Sum_Range)`

[image]

-----Update------

To get the unique date in column J from J2, you can try `=IFNA(INDEX(A:A,1+MATCH(,COUNTIF(J$1:J1,A$2:A$10),)),"")` and drag down.

There would be a value "0" as the blank cells between with different days. Then you can delete it.

[image]

Then you can get the sum.

[image]

Comment: thank you, Its kind of working. can you suggest me how  to list out the dates continuously in that column. in your answer the J column contains dates. How to fetch that date from my data automatically?
PS : I trade from monday to friday so the date will have weekends and holidays as gap.